# How to inject a view into a region via view model at program start

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, viewmodel, region

I am creating a WPF MVVM Prism application where I need to switch between views within a region, which I do with view injection. I instantiate the Region in `MainWindow.xaml` like this:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
```

Changing the views with commands later is no problem. The problem is that I need the region at program start to be able to show a view from the beginning. When I put that in the constructor like

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IContainerExtension container, IRegionManager regionManager)
{
   _regionManager = regionManager;
   _container = container;

   _view1 = _container.Resolve<1Control>();
   _view2 = _container.Resolve<2Control>();
   _contentregion = _regionManager.Regions["ContentRegion"];
   _contentregion.Add(_view1);
   _contentregion.Add(_view1);
}
```

I get the error that `RegionManager` does not contain `ContentRegion`. This is the case because it is not yet instantiated from XAML at that time.  I cannot use the main window and the `Loaded` event like [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/06-ViewActivationDeactivation/ActivationDeactivation), because I need to do it in the view model, instead of code-behind. It would also be enough to have a default view set somehow (in XAML Maybe?) and then later change the active view with commands, but I also don't see how that could work.

Comment: Please consider reading our [ask] topics. Your question is hard to read and is lacking the relevant code (to understand your setup). Please re-format your question and add the missing information.

Comment: you can do _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(regionName, viewType);

Comment: RegionManager sounds like something that needs to be initialized in App.xaml.cs, before any view or viewmodel are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want view injection or use the navigation framework and need to set an initial view, you can inject it or navigate to it using the region manager in the Prism application by overriding `OnInitialized` in *App.xaml.cs*.
It is important that you call `base.OnInitialized();` first, because it will call `Show()` on the shell window. Consequently, after this call the shell view is initialized and the region manager knows about its regions.

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
   // ...bootstrapping code.

   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
      base.OnInitialized();

      var regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
      var contentRegion = regionManager.Regions["ContentRegion"];

      var view1 = Container.Resolve<Control1>();
      var view2 = Container.Resolve<Control2>();
      contentRegion.Add(view1);
      contentRegion.Add(view1);
   }
}
```

Another approach is to use *view discovery* instead of *view injection*, where you register the view to a region with region manager using the `RegisterViewWithRegion` method. In your Prism application in *App.xaml.cs*, you can do that in different places like `CreateShell` or `OnInitialized`, because this method only *registers* the view with the region. It will be instantiated later when the region is available and the view is shown. Prism will create the view automatically and load it into the region.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   var regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
   regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(Control1));
   regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(Control2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think that answer my Question in case I can Access the Instances of the views in my ViewModel ( to Change activeness), so my follow up Question: To get the View Instances I think I Need the GetView Method. How can I name the Instances that the Method would actually recognize them?

Comment: @BadBinder Region instances have an overload for `Add`, that lets you specify a name for the view that is added: `Add(object view, string viewName)`. If you want to be aware of when a view is active, you should have a look at [`IActiveAware`](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Advanced-MVVM.html) and [navigation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Navigation.html) in Prism.